# RequireJS returns undefined module

Tags: javascript, dependencies, requirejs, require, web-development-server

I have a test suite that runs chronologically like this :

1. test1.js
2. test2.js

in test1.js I do :

```
define(['moduleA'], function (moduleA) ...
```

in test2.js I have another

```
define(['moduleA'], function (moduleA) ...
```

It seems that moduleA is defined in test1.js but it is undefined in test2.js. I can do a require in test2.js and it works fine.

Am I misunderstanding a fundamental aspect of requireJS? Is this the expected behaviour that requireJS will not define the same module twice under the same queue of execution?

Comment: If you invert the chronology, will test1.js have an issue? If so, then you've answered your question

Comment: even stranger is that they are both defined if the order is switched...